# `/bin/sh` not found in tox within Jenkins inside docker

Tags: python, docker, jenkins, tox

I am trying to setup a Jenkins pipeline which runs `tox` inside a docker container. There is a known issue that shebang lines get very long inside Jenkins, and [two solutions are proposed](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example/jenkins.html#avoiding-the-path-too-long-error-with-long-shebang-lines). The first is to use `--workdir` to select a shorter path. This option works in principle, but I loose the automatic unique path-names per project from Jenkins. I would thus prefer to use the second option, `TOX_LIMITED_SHEBANG`. Unfortunately, that seems to fail with the following error when the package under test is supposed to be installed: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "b'/bin/sh'": "b'/bin/sh'"`. I have verified that `/bin/sh` is in fact available in the docker container. The Jenkinsfile looks as follows:

```
node("docker") {
    // burnpanck/tox-base contains tox and many python versions
    docker.image('burnpanck/tox-base').inside {
        checkout scm
        stage('Matrix-test using Tox') {
            // verify that /bin/sh exists
            sh 'ls -al /bin'
            // the following does not work
            sh 'TOX_LIMITED_SHEBANG=1 tox -vv'
            // the following works 
            // sh 'tox --workdir=/var/jenkins_home/tox'
        }
    }
}
```

Tox is version 3.1.2 and runs under python 3.6 (the docker image is generated from this [Dockerfile](https://github.com/burnpanck/docker-tox-base/blob/master/Dockerfile)). What surprises me a little is the "b'/bin/sh'" coming from `str`-ing a `bytes` instance. Could it be that tox is in fact trying to run a program by the name `sh'` in the path `b'/bin`?

The `tox.ini` in use simply calls `pytest`:

```
[tox]
envlist = py36
[testenv]
recreate = True
commands =
    pytest
```

The full backtrace from tox (Jenkins console output) is the following:

```
py36 create: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/_debug_jenkins-long-shebang-L7UHBNCVPSOBSTKZ7COPFJBJLWR5XZXFIAD7TBGC4WQLVDLZYVQQ/.tox/py36
py36 inst: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/_debug_jenkins-long-shebang-L7UHBNCVPSOBSTKZ7COPFJBJLWR5XZXFIAD7TBGC4WQLVDLZYVQQ/.tox/dist/test_model-0.dev20180717.zip
ERROR: invocation failed (errno 2), args: [b'/bin/sh', '/var/jenkins_home/workspace/_debug_jenkins-long-shebang-L7UHBNCVPSOBSTKZ7COPFJBJLWR5XZXFIAD7TBGC4WQLVDLZYVQQ/.tox/py36/bin/pip', 'install', '/var/jenkins_home/workspace/_debug_jenkins-long-shebang-L7UHBNCVPSOBSTKZ7COPFJBJLWR5XZXFIAD7TBGC4WQLVDLZYVQQ/.tox/dist/test_model-0.dev20180717.zip'], cwd: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/_debug_jenkins-long-shebang-L7UHBNCVPSOBSTKZ7COPFJBJLWR5XZXFIAD7TBGC4WQLVDLZYVQQ
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/.pyenv/versions/3.6.6/bin/tox", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(cmdline())
  File "/.pyenv/versions/3.6.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tox/session.py", line 39, in cmdline
    main(args)
  File "/.pyenv/versions/3.6.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tox/session.py", line 45, in main
    retcode = Session(config).runcommand()
  File "/.pyenv/versions/3.6.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tox/session.py", line 422, in runcommand
    return self.subcommand_test()
  File "/.pyenv/versions/3.6.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tox/session.py", line 620, in subcommand_test
    self.installpkg(venv, path)
  File "/.pyenv/versions/3.6.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tox/session.py", line 561, in installpkg
    venv.installpkg(path, action)
  File "/.pyenv/versions/3.6.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tox/venv.py", line 277, in installpkg
    self._install([sdistpath], extraopts=extraopts, action=action)
  File "/.pyenv/versions/3.6.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tox/venv.py", line 342, in _install
    self.run_install_command(packages=packages, options=options, action=action)
  File "/.pyenv/versions/3.6.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tox/venv.py", line 314, in run_install_command
    redirect=self.session.report.verbosity < 2,
  File "/.pyenv/versions/3.6.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tox/venv.py", line 427, in _pcall
    return action.popen(args, cwd=cwd, env=env, redirect=redirect, ignore_ret=ignore_ret)
  File "/.pyenv/versions/3.6.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tox/session.py", line 153, in popen
    popen = self._popen(args, cwd, env=env, stdout=stdout, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
  File "/.pyenv/versions/3.6.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tox/session.py", line 248, in _popen
    env=env,
  File "/.pyenv/versions/3.6.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/.pyenv/versions/3.6.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1344, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "b'/bin/sh'": "b'/bin/sh'"
```

Comment: Basically yes, the string `/bin/sh` gets incorrectly mangled by whatever attempts to convert it to a byte string. Where does this conversion happen?

Comment: Can we see your `tox.ini` trimmed down to an absolute minimum that manifests that behaviour?

Comment: updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We currently have [an open bug](https://github.com/tox-dev/tox/issues/931) for this.  `TOX_LIMITED_SHEBANG` is broken when tox is running under python3.

The root cause is there's a `.decode()` missing and a list ends up with mixed `bytes` and `str` instances.

Workarounds until [I fix it](https://github.com/tox-dev/tox/pull/946) are to use tox with a python2 interpreter or don't use `TOX_LIMITED_SHEBANG`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me that bug! Unfortunately, my principles do not allow me to run anything under python 2 anymore ;-). So far, I worked without `TOX_LIMITED_SHEBANG`. I'll consider using bleeding-edge tox instead.

Comment: Don't blame you! Drop python 2!